# Having trouble with decimals within functions

Tags: python

I am a beginner at Python. I am learning python for college.

I am creating a program to find mean, median, and mode using functions.  Haven't gotten to mode yet.

**Problems**: both functions have trouble computing if there is a decimal in the code (1.2, 1.3, 7.423, etc). The median function will round numbers up if the median is meant to have a decimal.

Figuring out how to calculate mode is also hard. If someone can help me with that, that would be awesome.

Thanks for any help you can offer. This is my first time posting here.

Here is the code:

```
#instructions for user
print ("This program is designed to calculate mean, median, and mode.")
print ("I need you to type the numbers you desire to be calculated.")
print ("")
print ("NOTICE: Use the spacebar to separate your numbers.")
print ("")
print ("NOTICE: Press enter to finalize your numbers list.")
print ("")

#creates list of numbers
s = raw_input("Begin typing: ")
numbers = map(int, s.split())

#instructions for user
print ""
print "Type 'mean()' to calculate for mean."
print "Type 'median()' to calcuate for median."
print ""

#creates mean function
def mean():
    print "the mean is: " + str(sum(numbers)/len(numbers))

#creates median function
def median(): 
    print "the median is: " + str(sorted(numbers)[len(numbers)//2])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
numbers = map(int, s.split())
```

Using `int` truncates each number, rounding down to the nearest integer. Use `float` if you want to handle decimal places.

```
numbers = map(float, s.split())
```

Comment: Thank you. This fixes my mean function greatly. When I use my median function I still have problems. If i input 1 2 3 4 as my list, my median comes out to 3.0 which is incorrect. It should be 2.5

Comment: That's because you're just getting the middle element by integer division (`len(numbers)//2`); if you want to take the average of the middle two elements, you'll need a special case for when the length is even.

Comment: can you please give me some code to go off of. I am not sure I understand exactly.

Comment: `return numbers[len(numbers)//2] if len(numbers)%2 else (numbers[len(numbers)//2]+numbers[len(numbers)//2-1])/2.0`